# Update Database with Entity Framework on the build agent

Tags: entity-framework, continuous-integration, database-migration

Looking for a nice way to do database migrations in the VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) Builds? We have written a console app, which  basically does this:

```
 new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, MigrationsConfiguration>(true)
    .InitializeDatabase(context);
```

..but i am after a built-in way, possibly a VSTS build extension or something that could do this out-the-box. I can see there's something like this being released soon (https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Commands/) but atm I don't know of a neat way of doing this.

it might be possible to use the `migrate.exe` in the CI enviroment (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj618307.aspx);

has anyone had success with it?

Comment: We've had success with using migrate.exe, but we use TeamCity. Read more about our setup in my blog http://www.danmusk.com/run-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-from-teamcity-with-psake/